# Data returned from promises with AWS-SDK for node and bluebird

Tags: node.js, amazon-ec2, promise, bluebird, aws-sdk

I'm trying to fetch for each region in AWS all their Elastic IPs registered. The piece of code that I'm currently handling is the following:

```
logger.info('About to fetch Regions');
ec2.describeRegionsPromised({}).then(function (data) {
  var addressesPromises = [];

  logger.info('Fetched Regions');
  logger.info(data);

  _.forEach(data.Regions, function (region) {
    var ec2Addresses = _.create(ec2, {region: region.RegionName});

    addressesPromises.push(ec2Addresses.describeAddressesPromised());
  });

  logger.info('About to fetch addresses per region');

  return Promise.all(addressesPromises);
}).then(function (data) {
  logger.info('Fetched addresses per region');
  logger.debug(data);
}).catch(function (err) {
  logger.error('There was an error when fetching regions and addresses');
  logger.error(err);
});
```

This works ok, but my problem is that I'm looking at the second `.then` promised-callback function `data` parameter and its data is an array with **the same length of the regions returned on the first request**.

**I know that I'm only using 1 Elastic IP in one region. For alll the other regions I don't have any associated.**

The Regions returned are the following (it's actually a formatted JSON):

```
Regions=[RegionName=eu-west-1, Endpoint=ec2.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com, RegionName=ap-southeast-1, Endpoint=ec2.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com, RegionName=ap-southeast-2, Endpoint=ec2.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com, RegionName=eu-central-1, Endpoint=ec2.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com, RegionName=ap-northeast-1, Endpoint=ec2.ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com, RegionName=us-east-1, Endpoint=ec2.us-east-1.amazonaws.com, RegionName=sa-east-1, Endpoint=ec2.sa-east-1.amazonaws.com, RegionName=us-west-1, Endpoint=ec2.us-west-1.amazonaws.com, RegionName=us-west-2, Endpoint=ec2.us-west-2.amazonaws.com]
```

In JSON it would be:

```
{ Regions: [] } //and so on
```

And the Elastic IP returned are the following:

```
[ { Addresses: [ [PublicIp=XX.XX.XXX.XXX, AllocationId=eipalloc-XXXXXXXX, Domain=vpc] ] },
  { Addresses: [ [PublicIp=XX.XX.XXX.XXX, AllocationId=eipalloc-XXXXXXXX, Domain=vpc] ] },
  { Addresses: [ [PublicIp=XX.XX.XXX.XXX, AllocationId=eipalloc-XXXXXXXX, Domain=vpc] ] },
  { Addresses: [ [PublicIp=XX.XX.XXX.XXX, AllocationId=eipalloc-XXXXXXXX, Domain=vpc] ] },
  { Addresses: [ [PublicIp=XX.XX.XXX.XXX, AllocationId=eipalloc-XXXXXXXX, Domain=vpc] ] },
  { Addresses: [ [PublicIp=XX.XX.XXX.XXX, AllocationId=eipalloc-XXXXXXXX, Domain=vpc] ] },
  { Addresses: [ [PublicIp=XX.XX.XXX.XXX, AllocationId=eipalloc-XXXXXXXX, Domain=vpc] ] },
  { Addresses: [ [PublicIp=XX.XX.XXX.XXX, AllocationId=eipalloc-XXXXXXXX, Domain=vpc] ] },
  { Addresses: [ [PublicIp=XX.XX.XXX.XXX, AllocationId=eipalloc-XXXXXXXX, Domain=vpc] ] } ]
```

On the response, I have an array of objects where their object key-values are all the same per each region request, which is false.

I would have expected in the second response the values resolution per each region, having the rest of them set to null, undefined, or similar.

**To sum up. I don't get why resolving the values of an array of promises (using .all) will get an array of identical values in each spot - not being the expected result.**

What's going on here? Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is the `Regions=[...]` expression? It's neither JSON nor array literal.

Comment: It was the output of ``winston`` doing ``.info()``. Imagine it as a regular JSON, like:
``{ Regions: [] }``
I have just edited the post. Thanks.

Comment: The only thing that would make sense is for `data.Regions` to be an array of objects, each with `.RegionName` and `.Endpoint` properties, but winston's `.info()` seems to be doing a good job of hiding the object `{}` structures and making `data.Regions` look like a flat array. Is that correct?

Comment: It could be. But what I'm trying to figure out is why the result of resolving all Elastic IPs requests per region is the same, with the same value across the array spots, knowing that I only have one Elastic IP in one region.

Comment: Well, I don't understand everything in the question but the simple answer would appear to be that `ec2Addresses.describeAddressesPromised()` does not deliver the data you expect, and maybe because the expression `_.create(ec2, {region: region.RegionName})` is somehow incorrect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue.
As @Roamer-1888 indicated the creation of the ec2Addresses object was incorrect. Instead, I should have created a new instance using the AWS SDK constructor for EC2 objects. However, the key-point of the issue was another one. Firstly the code...

```
logger.info('About to fetch Regions');
ec2.describeRegionsPromised({}).then(function (data) {
  var addressesPromises = [];

  logger.info('Fetched Regions');

  _.forEach(data.Regions, function (region) {
    var ec2Addresses = AWS.ec2(
      {
        region: region.RegionName,
        endpoint: region.Endpoint
      }
    );
    addressesPromises.push(ec2Addresses.describeAddressesPromised());
  });
  logger.info('About to fetch addresses per region');

  return Promise.all(addressesPromises);
}).then(function (data) {
  logger.info(arguments);
  logger.info('Fetched addresses per region');
  logger.debug(data);
}).catch(function (err) {
  logger.error('There was an error when fetching regions and addresses');
  logger.error(err);
});
```

As you can notice here, `ec2Addresses` is created invoking `AWS.ec2()` and not `new AWS.ec2()`, this is because the AWS-promised module creates the object and return it back promisifying it. (https://github.com/davidpelayo/aws-promised/blob/master/ecs.js):

```
'use strict';

var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
var memoize = require('lodash/function/memoize');
var promisifyAll = require('./lib/util/promisifyAll');

function ecs(options) {
  return promisifyAll(new AWS.ECS(options));
}

/**
 * Returns an instance of AWS.ECS which has Promise methods
 * suffixed by "Promised"
 *
 * e.g.
 * createService => createServicePromised
 *
 * @param options
 */
module.exports = memoize(ecs);
```

The issue was the last line of code:
`module.exports = memoize(ecs)`
This line of code **was caching the previous execution including its previous configuration**.

It turns out I ended up debugging the application and I realise the regions and endpoints were the array of promises were being executed were the same, and there was an error there.

By deleting the `memoize(ecs)` the expected result is the one I'm getting:

```
info: Fetched addresses per region
debug:  Addresses=[], Addresses=[], Addresses=[], Addresses=[], Addresses=[], Addresses=[PublicIp=XX.XXX.XXX.XXX, AllocationId=eipalloc-XXXXXX, Domain=vpc], Addresses=[], Addresses=[], Addresses=[]
```

Thanks for reading and helping.

Answer (score 0):

I found out a way of requesting addresses of different regions without creating a new EC2 object. In other words, by reusing the existing EC2 instance, by switching the endpoint like follows:

```
_.forEach(data.Regions, function (region) {
    //var ec2Addresses = AWS.ec2(
    //  {
    //    region: region.RegionName,
    //    endpoint: region.Endpoint
    //  }
    //);
    var ep = new AWS.Endpoint(region.Endpoint);
    ec2.config.region = region.RegionName;
    ec2.endpoint = ep;
    addressesPromises.push(ec2.describeAddressesPromised());
  });
  logger.info('About to fetch addresses per region');
```